# text() isn't working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`text()` function of jQuery isn't working on second click as seen in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SheikhNaveed/hL396/)

Here is HTML Code:

```
<div class="mb20"></div>
<nav id="lastNavigation" class="d row clearfix">
    <aside class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="col-xs-12 lessonNavigation lesson">
            <ul class="expandable">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>L1<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>L2<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>L3<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#"> 
                        <span>L4<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>L5<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
</nav>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var count = $('.lessonNavigation li').length;

//========================= Module and Unit Navigation ==================================

if (count > 10 && count <= 18) {
    $('.lessonNavigation li').attr('class', 'contracted');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(0)').attr('class', 'expanded left');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(1)').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:eq(2)').attr('class', 'expanded right');
}

//========================= Expand all navigation by clicking 'contracted' ==============

$('.tilesToggle').click(function () {
    $(this).text('Close').toggleClass('tilesToggle tilesToggleClose');
    $('.expandable').attr('class', 'expanded');
    $('ul.expanded li.activeLesson').attr('class', 'selected');
    $('ul.expanded li:not(.selected)').attr('class', '');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:even').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:odd').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
    $('.icon-arrow-left, .icon-arrow-right').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.tilesToggleClose').click(function () {
    $(this).text('See All').toggleClass('tilesToggleClose tilesToggle');
    $('ul.expanded li.selected').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
});
```

Comment: You might be better off using `$(this).html();`

Comment: The problem isn't with `.text()`, it's that your click handler isn't called at all.

Comment: I'm asking about second block of jquery where it says .text('See All'). Call function is calling becuase .toggleClass('tilesToggleClose tilesToggle'); after .text('See All') is working

Comment: No it isn't. It's calling the first click function again and that also does the `.toggleClass()`. (Put some `console.log()` statements in each function and you'll see for yourself.)

Comment: the `'.tilesToggleClose'` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with `.text()`, it's that your second click handler isn't called at all. When you say:

```
$('.tilesToggleClose').click(function () {
```

...you are binding a click handler to any elements that have that class *at that moment,* not to elements that might have that class in future at the time the click occurs. So it is your first click handler that is called on all clicks on the element.

You could use delegated event handlers bound to a parent element:

```
$('div.lesson').on('click','.tilesToggle', function () {
   ...
});
$('div.lesson').on('click','.tilesToggleClose', function () {
   ...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hL396/2/

But it might be easier to just bind one click handler to the element that will have the `.tilesToggle` class when `.click()` is called, and then within the handler test the class:

```
$('.tilesToggle').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('tilesToggleClose')) {
        $this.text('See All');
        $('ul.expanded li.selected').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    } else {
        $this.text('Close');
        $('.expandable').attr('class', 'expanded');
        $('ul.expanded li.activeLesson').attr('class', 'selected');
        $('ul.expanded li:not(.selected)').attr('class', '');
        $('.lessonNavigation li:even').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
        $('.lessonNavigation li:odd').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
        $('.icon-arrow-left, .icon-arrow-right').css('display', 'none');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('tilesToggle tilesToggleClose');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hL396/3/

Answer (score 0):

It's not calling because the click handler is initialized before it has the class.
Fix:

```
function showTiles() {
    $(this).text('Close').addClass('isShowingTiles');
    $('.expandable').attr('class', 'expanded');
    $('ul.expanded li.activeLesson').attr('class', 'selected');
    $('ul.expanded li:not(.selected)').attr('class', '');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:even').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:odd').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
    $('.icon-arrow-left, .icon-arrow-right').css('display', 'none');
}

function hideTiles() {
    $(this).text('See All').removeClass('isShowingTiles');
    $('ul.expanded li.selected').attr('class', 'activeLesson');

}


$('.tilesToggle').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("isShowingTiles")){
        showTiles.apply($(this));
    }
    else{
        hideTiles.apply($(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you want to expand the `li` on second click and set the text to `SeeAll`

I used a simple `if-else` flag

```
var flag = false;
$('.tilesToggle').click(function () {
    if (!flag){
        $(this).text('Close');
    $('.expandable').attr('class', 'expanded');
    $('ul.expanded li.activeLesson').attr('class', 'selected');
    $('ul.expanded li:not(.selected)').attr('class', '');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:even').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('.lessonNavigation li:odd').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
    $('.icon-arrow-left, .icon-arrow-right').css('display', 'none');
        flag = true;
    }else{
        $(this).text('See All');
        $('ul.expanded li.selected').attr('class', 'activeLesson');
        flag = false;
    }

});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/hL396/6/)